# How to set the 513th bit of a char[1024] in C?

Tags: c, arrays, char, bit-manipulation

I was recently asked in an interview how to set the 513th bit of a `char[1024]` in C, but I'm unsure how to approach the problem. I saw [How do you set, clear, and toggle a single bit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47981/how-do-you-set-clear-and-toggle-a-single-bit-in-c), but how do I choose the bit from such a large array?

Comment: Do you actually mean bit, or do you mean the 513th byte? A `char[1024]` is an array of 1024 bytes; the 513th bit would be in the middle of the 64th byte, but it seems very unlikely that's what you're talking about

Comment: It seems clear that the questioner is asking about the 513th bit.

Comment: I am quite sure its bit  and that has to be set !

Comment: @JonathanGrynspan : Well Thanks to the community help I will surely be able answer similar and related questions in the next interview .

Comment: @JonathanGrynspan : Learning is something I have learnt to do quickly. So I think I can survive. Thank you for your concern , much appreciated

Comment: A big thanks to everyone who helped me out with this question, I attended another interview and this time I got a similar Question right , check the status of 177th bit of char[100].

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
int bitToSet = 513;
inArray[bitToSet / 8] |= (1 << (bitToSet % 8));
```

...making certain assumptions about character size and desired endianness.

EDIT: Okay, fine. You can replace `8` with `CHAR_BIT` if you want.

Answer (score 4):

```
#include <limits.h>

int charContaining513thBit = 513 / CHAR_BIT;
int offsetOf513thBitInChar = 513 - charContaining513thBit*CHAR_BIT;

int bit513 = array[charContaining513thBit] >> offsetOf513thBitInChar & 1;
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to know the width of characters (in bits) on your machine. For pretty much everyone, that's 8. You can use the constant `CHAR_BIT` from `limits.h` in a C program. You can then do some fairly simple math to find the offset of the bit (depending on how you count them).

Numbering bits from the left, with the 2⁷ bit in a[0] being bit 0, the 2⁰ bit being bit 7, and the 2⁷ bit in a[1] being bit 8, this gives:

```
offset = 513 / CHAR_BIT;  /* using integer (truncating) math, of course */
bit = 513 % CHAR_BIT;
a[offset] |= (0x80>>bit)
```

There are many sane ways to number bits, here are two:

```
 a[0]                      a[1]
 0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7     8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15     This is the above
 7  6  5  4  3  2  1  0    15 14 13 12 11 10  9  8     This is |= (1<<bit)
```

You could also number from the other end of the array (treating it as one very large big-endian number).

Answer (score 2):

Small optimization:

The / and % operators are rather slow, even on a lot of modern cpus, with modulus being slightly slower.  I would replace them with the equivalent operations using bit shifting (and subtraction), which only works nicely when the second operand is a power of two, obviously.

x / 8 becomes x >> 3
x % 8 becomes x-((x>>3)<<3)
 for this second operation, just reuse the result from the initial division.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the desired order (left to right versus right to left), it might change.  But the general idea assuming 8 bits per byte would be to choose the byte as.  This is expanded into lots of lines of code to hopefully show more clearly the intended steps (or perhaps it just obfuscates the intention):

```
int bitNum = 513;
int bytePos = bitNum / 8;
```

Then the bit position would be computed as:

```
int bitInByte = bitNum % 8;
```

Then set the bit (assuming the goal is to set it to 1 as opposed to clear or toggle it):

```
charArray[bytePos] |= ( 1 << bitInByte );
```

Answer (score 0):

When you say 513th are you using index 0 or 1 for the 1st bit? If it's the former your post refers to the bit at index 512. I think the question is valid since everywhere else in C the first index is always 0.

BTW

```
static char chr[1024];
...
chr[512>>3]=1<<(512&0x7);
```